# How do you transpose tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, transpose

We transpose a matrix $A$ by replacing $A_{ij}$ with $A_{ji}$, for all $i$ and $j$.

However, in case $A$ has more than two dimensions (that is, it is a tensor), I don't know how to apply the transpose operation.

1. If A has dimensions $3\times 3 \times 8$, then what will replace $A_{ijk}$?
2. If $A$ has shape $3\times 3\times 8\times 8$, then what will replace $A_{ijkl}$?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a transpose defined for 3D arrays. What does your matrix represent? Can you provide more context for your question? Does the matrix represent a linear transformation of some kind, or is it just a container for data?

Comment: You can take A as a 3D tensor and 4D as $\frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d}q}$ where q is an $8 \times 1$ vector

Comment: I doubt there's going to be a unique notion of 'tensor transpose.' If you've $n$ indices, then there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to pick some pair of indices to swap. Each of these generates a certain kind of transposition; moreover, we can compose them together to form any permutation of the indices that we like (a total of $n!$ if we include the identity permutation.) So without additional context I wouldn't expect a unique tensor transpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operation of taking a transpose is closely related to the concept of symmetry.  One paper that addresses this is http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2010/WCE2010_pp1838-1841.pdf. I have been researching $2^m$ dimensional matrices where the indices are zeros and ones.  The transpose is found by changing all zeros to ones and ones to zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for 3D array,

First decide if it's row major (e.g. C) or column major (e.g. Fortran).

For a C array A[n3][n2][n1], the fastest dimension is n1, and we can name this original sequence as 321.

Then we can say we want a 321 -> 132 transpose operation, which is to copy the array element A[i3][i2][i1] to B[i1][i3][i2].

Often we assume from fastest dimension to slowest dimension being 123, then we can call the above transpose operation as 231 (i.e., 123->231).